# Typescript issue with dynamic types of argument

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics, typescript-eslint

I'm trying to make getter and setter in Typescript and facing issues with dynamic types of arguments.

```
interface PersonType {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const person: PersonType = {
  name: '',
  age: 0
};

const setPersonKey = ({ key, value }: { key: keyof PersonType; value: PersonType[keyof PersonType] }) => {
  person[key] = value; // ERROR -> Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
}


const getPersonKey = ({ key }: { key: keyof PersonType; }): PersonType[keyof PersonType] => {
  return person[key];
}
```

I have 3 issues with the above code

1. `person[key]` throws an error in `setPersonKey` function
2. `value` type is not dynamic based on the `key` passed in `setPersonKey` function
3. return type of `getPersonKey` function is not dynamic based on `key` value

Would really appreciate a reference doc and an explanation of the solution.

Typescript playground for testing:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play

Comment: why didn't you do  `const person : PersonType = {`?

Comment: Have tried that, but the error does not change. I will update the question to remove this confusion.

Comment: `typescript-typings` is a tag very specifically regarding a type library system and indicates clearly in all-caps "DO NOT USE IT AS A SYNONYM OF TYPES".

Comment: @crashmstr was not aware, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the argument type - `{ key: keyof PersonType; value: PersonType[keyof PersonType] }` is an object with a `key` property, that is a key of `PersonType`(OK), and a `value` property that is of the same type as **any** value of `PersonType`, **not necessarily the same as `key`**.

Try this to make the compiler understand that key and value refer to the same proprty of `PersonType`::

```js
const setPersonKey = <K extends keyof PersonType>({ key, value }: { key: K; value: PersonType[K] }) => {
  person[key] = value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick help. Working sample here https://replit.com/@RajRohit/AutopickType#index.ts