# Infer possible values from a key within an interface

Tags: typescript

I want to infer the possible values for the `value` property, depending on the key. For example, if the key is name, the value should be a string. If the key is age, the value should be a number. The way it is now, we can correctly choose a key, but no matter what the key is - the value is either string or number (it takes all possible values due to `MainEntity[keyof MainEntity]`. How can I infer only the possible values for the specific key?

```
interface Example<MainEntity> {
  key: keyof MainEntity;
  data: {
    value: MainEntity[keyof MainEntity];
  };
}

interface Entity {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const fn = (obj: Example<Entity>) => {};
fn({ key: 'name', data: { value: '14' } });
```

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73124605) it is a similar case I think. For this case I propose: `interface Example<MainEntity, K extends keyof MainEntity> {
  key: K;
  data: {
    value: MainEntity[K];
  };
}`. This way you always have to specify the key in the type, like `const fn = (obj: Example<Entity, 'name'>) => {};`

Comment: Yeah, but let's say we have 10 fields or more and we want to build an object with a similar interface. We have to infer the possible values just by filling the key property. I mean, what I'm asking, is it possible in TS? Couldn't find a similar thread and I had never done sth like this until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link `key` to `data.value` so something like this

```js
interface Example<MainEntity, K extends keyof MainEntity> {
  key: K;
  data: {
    value: MainEntity[K];
  }
}
      
interface Entity {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
      
const fn = <K extends keyof Entity>(obj: Example<Entity, K>) => {};
fn({ key: 'name', data: { value: '14' } });
```

`fn` can also be defined like this

```js
const fn = (obj: {[K in keyof Entity]: Example<Entity, K>}[keyof Entity]) => {};
```